# Invalid OAuth Signature returned while using Yammer Api

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, http-authentication, signpost

I am trying to write a small webapp that pulls data from Yammer. I have to go through Yammer's OAuth bridge to access their data. I tried using the [Oauth php library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/) and do the 3 way handshake. But at the last step, I get an error stating I have an invalid OAuth Signature.

Here are the series of steps:

1. The first part involves getting the request Token URL and these are the query parameters that I pass.

   ```
       [oauth_version] => 1.0
       [oauth_nonce] => 4e495b6a5864f5a0a51fecbca9bf3c4b
       [oauth_timestamp] => 1256105827
       [oauth_consumer_key] => my_consumer_key
       [oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1
       [oauth_signature] => FML2eacPNH6HIGxJXnhwQUHPeOY=
   ```
2. Once this step is complete, I get the request Token as follows:

   [oauth_token] => 6aMcbRK5wMqHgZQsdfsd
   [oauth_token_secret] => ro8AJxZ67sUDoiOTk8sl4V3js0uyof1uPJVB14asdfs
   [oauth_callback_confirmed] => true
3. I then try to authorize the given token and token secret by passing the parameters to the authorize url.It takes me to Yammer's authentication page where I have allow my app to talk to Yammer.
4. Yammer then gives me a 4 digit code that I have to put back into my application which then tries to acquire the permanent access token. I pass the following information to the access token URL:

   ```
       [oauth_version] => 1.0
       [oauth_nonce] => 52b22495ecd9eba277c1ce6b97b00fdc
       [oauth_timestamp] => 1256106815
       [oauth_consumer_key] => myconsumerkey
       [callback_token] => 61A7
       [oauth_token] => 6aMcbRK5wMqHgZQsdfsd
       [oauth_token_secret] => ro8AJxZ67sUDoiOTk8sl4V3js0uyof1uPJVB14asdfs
       [oauth_callback_confirmed] => true
       [oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1
       [oauth_signature] => V9YcMDq2rP7OiZTK1k5kb/otMzA=
   ```
5. Here I am supposed to receive the Oauth Permanent access token, but instead I get a **Invalid Oauth signature**. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I use the same signaures to sign the request. Should I sign the request using the new token and secret? I tried that as well but to no avail. I even tried implementing this in java using [signpost library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) and got stuck at the exact same place. Help Help!!

Answer (score 0):

The `callback_token` was something Yammer introduced in response to an OAuth security advisory earlier this year. When OAuth 1.0a was released, it was instead named `oauth_verifier`. However, it's not unlikely that Yammer still supports their workaround but rename it and try again to be sure.

Also, the below is information from the Yammer Development Network yesterday:

> Tomorrow we will be releasing some
>   changes to the Yammer API to
>   facilitate user network switching on
>   API clients. Most of the change is in
>   the OAuth Access Tokens call which
>   allows you to generate pre-authorized
>   OAuth access tokens for a given user.
>   One token will be generated for each
>   network they are in and your clients
>   switch networks by sending an API
>   request signed with the appropriate
>   token for that network.

I'm assuming that Yammer OAuth libraries might need to be updated per this change. I haven't taken a look at it yet.

**Edit:** My [python-yammer-oauth](http://github.com/lemonad/python-yammer-oauth) library still works despite Yammer having changed things on their side.

**Edit2:** Could you try using signature method `PLAINTEXT` instead of `HMAC-SHA1`? I've had problems with Yammer and HMAC-SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by using PLAINTEXT.. but for this method its giving me the same "Invalid OAuth signature" error even for requesting the token.

So is it possible to generate the access token we use HMAC-SHA1 and for accessing the actual API method i.e. for posting the message.. we use PLAINTEXT?

Answer (score 0):

just found the problem!

I had forgotten to add an ampersand ("&") at the end of CONSUMER_SECRET. Perhaps this is your issue as well?